# Slack bot not pausing in while loop instead restarting at while true statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack-api, slack

I'm working on a bot for slack. What my issue is, I want that when a person pings the bot with certain text (@bot log) that it asks for a email address, then repeats the email back and asks for confirmation.

This all works and where my troubles begin. When you respond to the confirmation it repeats back what you just said again and does not move forward to saying the "got it your username is".

```
if command.startswith(LOG):
    slack_client.rtm_send_message(channel, "Please input your username:")
    while True:
        for slack_message in slack_client.rtm_read():

            message = slack_message.get("text")
            user = slack_message.get("user")
            if not message or not user:
                continue
            slack_client.rtm_send_message(channel, "You Wrote :  " + message +  "\n is that your correct email?")
    else:
        print("That didnt work")
            #break  ##ask for confirmation, maybe the text in this line can reference in a different way
            #while True:
        respond = slack_message.get("text")
        while respond is 'yes' or 'Yes':##would this to true already, push in regex
                continue
        slack_client.rtm_send_message(channel, "Got it, your username is :" + message)#possibly grabbing newest text and not variable of message
                #if respond != 'yes' or 'Yes':#push from regex above
                    #slack_client.rtm_send_message(channel, "sorry!")                   
        time.sleep(.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`while True` is being executed indefinitle in a loop; you have to exit it somehow using either `break` or `return`. But both `break` and `return` will ignore your `else` after `while` so you have to refactor your code significantly. Something like this:

```
while True:
    for slack_message in slack_client.rtm_read():
        message = slack_message.get("text")
        user = slack_message.get("user")
        if not message or not user:
            continue
        slack_client.rtm_send_message(…)
        break
# and no else here
print(…)
```

And I don't think you need first `while True` at all. Let me rewrite the code this way:

```
while True:
    command = ??? # slack_client.rtm_read() perhaps?
    if command.startswith(LOG):
        slack_client.rtm_send_message(channel, "Please input your username:")
        for slack_message in slack_client.rtm_read():
            message = slack_message.get("text")
            user = slack_message.get("user")
            if not message or not user:
                continue
            slack_client.rtm_send_message(channel, "You Wrote :  " + message +  "\n is that your correct email?")

        while True:
            respond = slack_message.get("text")
            if respond is 'yes' or 'Yes':##would this to true already, push in regex
                continue
            break
        slack_client.rtm_send_message(channel, "Got it, your username is :" + message)#possibly grabbing newest text and not variable of message
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. The first half of this works correctly. Its more of the linking into the second portion if you could shed some light on that it might resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments lol sorry for late response I was playing with these suggestions and got lost until you posted this code. I'm working with the changes right now. unfortunately though now it stops working after the first time it responds ("Please input your username")

Comment: So you need it to work forever? That I didn't understand, I thought it's a one off task. Ok, then let's me restore the first `while True` back into the code.

Comment: well in this instance its for a person to essentially log in. so really I just want them to say @bot login and it asks for username, repeats back to them and then confirms. that way I can save that as a variable

Comment: Well, you get the idea, the rest is up to you. I'm sure you can adapt the code as you want — one time or infiite loop, or whatever. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you going to play with it more. Appreciate the help